# finding an absolute value inequality

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

The question asks, "find an absolute value inequality whose solution's are x>2 and x<-12". I have no idea where to start and was wondering if anyone could help

Answer (score 3):

Hint: the midpoint of $2$ and $-12$ is $-5$.  Look at a number line.

Comment: So should I just add the midpoint to both sides? I tried that and i it didn't come out even close to  to close to each other

Comment: Think about distance to the midpoint.